# How maliciously made multiple user registrations are managed on a real world website?

Tags: security, registration

I've notoced lots of websites allow users to register by simply asking their email and password [aside all the other information like name, username, genre etc.]. And the users don't have to do email verification as they register, they simply have a reminder that they should verify their email, but otherwise they can use the website normally. This is very good for UX, since the user can immediately start using a website and not wasting time to do email verifications etc. before he knows whether he will keep using this website or not.
So the question I wanted to ask is the following:
Suppose a malicious user writes a program that will keep registering users with valid usernames and valid(syntactically) emails.
This will eventually cause lost of trouble if not correctly managed:

- the database will eventually run out of ids for users
- This will create lots of records, thus eating up space
- More user records, means more lookup time

So, I'm really curious how all this is managed, if at all.
NOTE: most of websites I'm talking about, do not use CAPTCHA(bad for UX), so they manage the issue in some other way, again, if at all.
but neither the solution is to delete the record if the user hasn't confirmed his/her email in a time term. For suppose user looses Internet connection[, or forgets, or anything else] the last day he has to verify email. So the user will loose his/her account and just forget about that website. So this is not a solution.
 not sure about IP limitations. But suppose that is an Internet cafe and users keep registering. And there are dynamic IPs these days. Is limiting the registration to some amount of time a solution? But how do I know when the last registration occurred if the IP keeps changing. So how is this issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an SO problem. This site is more focused on solving issues with actual code rather than ways to solve a generalise problem.

That said, the current patterns seem to be...

1. Require more information. By having more information, you can de duplicate accounts. That said, in your scenario repeated accounts with the same email address should be easily consolidated. This doesn't prevent bots from registering many accounts with different addresses, but adding more requirements, such as address and phone number make it increasingly differcult to match data sets to your validation.
2. Validate via email. Contrary to what you suggest, this is still quite common and a good means to weed out genuine users with interest in the site from the chaff.
3. The other option is a federated authentication service such as Facebook, Twitter, Google+. These provide the UX you seek, but without it being your problem to validate.

From your comments that these changes aren't an option...

Your other option is to look at something server side. This will be along the lines of blocking by IP address. The problem I'd have with this is that the user is unaware, at least with the other options presented the user isn't going to get denied based upon something that happens backend. These measures can still be easily circumvented. An IP block can only be implemented for a short period of time, so the rogue registrations just need to delay long enough or more likely flip between different IP addresses.

Comment: Requiring more information is not an option, the user still don't know the website but I'm already asking a whole lot about him. And it's easy to fake information. The email adress keeps changing. Suppose multiple for loops generationg valid emails. And no phone verification is required, maybe eventually but not right when the user registers. I noticed lots of websites stopped requiring phone numbers in this way, as this annoys users and you cannot know whether that user has a phone at all. And these sites do not use federated authentication. There must be some other way around this.

Comment: One other option would be to leverage cookies. Within your registration form, create a cookie on the client. That can be some session ident initially posted from the server. When the registration form is posted back, you can inspect the cookie server side to make sure it matches up. If it doesn't then deny the registration. That would at least prevent automated clients from posting registrations and require something akin to a modern browser.